# Coffee Break Riddle

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Here's a little brain teaser, for your coffee break:

$$
62-63 = 1
$$

Move only **one** digit to make it right!

Have fun!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe that following expression  is unique solution to the riddle :

$2^6-63=1$

Answer (score 45):

(By request...)

If we can move one "character", then moving the horizontal line over gives $62 = 63 - 1$

Answer (score 43):

$6263 \neq 1$.

I moved one character not a digit :)